# Algorithm in R to predict next value based on history

Tags: r, algorithm

I have a data set with dates, interval between those dates, and an order quantity:

```
set.seed(13)
ord.interval <- sample(c(14, 28, 42), 
            size = 25, 
            replace = TRUE, 
            prob = c(0.7, 0.2, 0.1))

week <- as.Date("2013-01-13")
for (i in 2:25) {
  week[i] <- week[i-1] + ord.interval[i]
}

set.seed(13)
ord.qty <- sample(c(0,1,2,3),
                  size = 25,
                  replace = T,
                  prob = c(0.2, 0.6, 0.1, 0.1))

df <- data.frame(week, ord.interval, ord.qty)
```

Let's assume it is 2014-04-06 (two weeks after the last week in our data set) and I want to know what I should suggest as my order.qty for that date. What's the best algorithmic approach?

I tried implementing the following type of solution:

```
if: (number of days since last order) >= (average interval between last 7 orders)

then: suggest the average of the last 7 order.qty

else: suggest 0
```

but the variability was too high to use a rolling average. Is there a better way to try to predict this, or am I staring at machine learning and am just not smart enough to realize it?

Comment: If you need suggestions on how to model your data to make predictions, then perhaps you should ask your question over at [stats.se] or maybe [DataScience.SE]. Right now you don't have a specific programming question here. You need to decide what's right for your data and the properties of the predictions you want to make. Once you know exactly _what_ you want to do, but don't know _how_ to do it, then you can ask here.

Comment: @MrFlick thank you for the suggestion, I'll move my question over there. I'm new to StackExchange and StackOverflow

Comment: Try to be explicit about what criteria you want to use to decide on a "best" method when you move your question.

Comment: Not sure if either of CV or DS are suitable. You have a known model and try to find good predictions of the model. If you formalize this model a little and define what a "good prediction" is (low MAD, high likelyhood, ...?), this might be good for [Math.SE].